# How to remove labels that values are equal to zero. I have a chart that has a lot of labels, but only a few have values 0<. How to display only values

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2016

I have an excel tower graph that is linked to a table that has a lot of categories. Most of these categories contain values that are 0 but may be changed to a value greater than 0 in the future. Since the chart is auto updating based on the values in the chart, is there a way to make the graph only show the values greater then 0.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Depending on exactly what you want for results, you could either use a fliter to filter out the zero's, or you could replace the zeros with `#NA`

Comment: The chart contains 2 rows, one with the names and one with the values. Is it possible to remove the names if ther value is = to 0, or n/a